# The system cannot find the file specified at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start

Tags: java, ant

I am a novice at programming. I have recently tried to download the source code of an open source  software and setup the environment. However, I am seeing the following issue when I tried to run the build for the first time:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "unzip" (in directory "....\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start

Any tips on how to resolve this issue?

From what I understand, it is unable to a file:

1. where exactly to look for `ProcessBuilder.start`
2. How do I modify it?

Comment: check specific target in build.xml file and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("Write command here").start();
```

Edit: Command - string array which begin with fullpath to your programm. For example:

```
processBuilder.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\OUTLOOK.exe").start();
```

Comment: I have tried what was suggested here, but I'm still seeing the following error, with the change.

ProcessUtils.java:24: error: incompatible types: Process cannot be converted to ProcessBuilder
[javac]     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("..\\..\\..\\Arduino\\build", "/a").start();


The following is without the change:

Arduino\build\build.xml:844: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "unzip" (in directory "..\..\Arduino\build"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Earlier the code was a follows:

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdLine);

It looks like it is parsing the command line as follows.
cmdLine[i] = command[i].replace("\"", "\\\"");


ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Sandhya\\Desktop\\Arduino_clone\\Arduino\\build").start();

But then I am seeing the following now.

\ProcessUtils.java:24: error: incompatible types: Process cannot be converted to ProcessBuilder
    [javac]     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:..\\..\\Arduino_clone\\Arduino\\build").start();

Comment: Try to do that: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(); Add extension of "build": processBuilder.command("C:..\\..\\Arduino_clone\\Arduino\\build.exe").st‌​art();